# Passing a string back from C++/CLI to VBA

Tags: c#, c++, vba, ms-access

OK, I'm going slightly mad here.
I have this C++/CLI declaration:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall Command(const char* commandName, const char* arguments, char* %result, int %resultLength) {
    System::String^ commandNameS = gcnew System::String(commandName);
    System::String^ argumentsS = gcnew System::String(arguments);
    System::String^ resultS = gcnew System::String(' ', 1000);
    int x = MainFunc::Command(commandNameS, argumentsS, resultS);
    resultLength = resultS->Length;

    char* str2 = (char*)(void*)System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(resultS);

    //result = str2;
    return x;
}
```

commandName and arguments go in correctly from VBA.

resultLength goes back correctly to VBA.

If I debug, str2 appears to hold the correct value (a hex value followed by a correct string in the debugger)

If I uncomment the //result = str2; line, I get a crash.
Repeated debugging attempts get me to this error information:

*MSACCESS.EXE has triggered a breakpoint. occurred

```
ntdll.dll!_RtlReportCriticalFailure@12()    Unknown Symbols loaded.
oleaut32.dll!_SysFreeString@4() Unknown Symbols loaded.
```

A heap has been corrupted 
0xC0000374*

So I suspect I need something to pin or hold the allocation of the string before passing it back to VBA

VBA6 declaration for Win32:

```
Private Declare Function Command Lib "External.Win32.dll" (ByVal CommandName As String, ByVal Argument As String, ByRef Result As String, ByRef ResultLength As Long) As Long
```

**EDIT:**
Using *result = *str2; shows result equal to the first character in str2, but seems to still result in an empty string on the VBA side.  No crash though.

Comment: can you try "*result" = *str2;"

result = str2; should make result point to str2 - which points to the String.

Comment: The VBA runtime expects you to create a BSTR.  It tries to release that string after the call with SysFreeString(), kaboom because it is not such a string and allocated on the wrong heap.  SysAllocString() or Marshal::StringToBSTR() required.

Comment: @Hans - not via the C style DECLARE calls, the convention automatically converts to/from ANSI unless they are mapped as pointers instead of strings.

Comment: @TomSöhne hmm, returns an empty string but no error I think.  Debugger:  -  str2 0x12cf7e78 "Between 25-Jan-2018 02:00 PM And 26-Jan-2018 02:00 PM|Product:  1 - WHEAT NZ|All Mill Systems|" char *  and  result 0x12d56b54 "B" char * &

Comment: the Addresses are not the same, ok my guess was wrong.
can you try strcpy/strncpy instead of *result = *str2 ?

Comment: It complained about strcpy.  I had to use strcopy_s instead, which still caused a crash though.

Comment: Ah, I have  to initialise the string I pass in to all null char, so I can't pass back a completely new string, but I can update the contents of an existing one. :(

Comment: makes sense - since you pass a pointer to some memory allocated by access.

Comment: Yeah.  I was just hoping to be able to update the reference rather than allocate a (e.g.) 10K string on every call when it will almost never have anything in it coming back.